# Is my network configuration is efficient for security?

Tags: network

I enabled the "Guest Wifi Network" from the router configuration menu. 
Now I have two different wifi networks on my router (with different IP address).

The first one is for "trusted" devices - my professional computer and my smartphone. Only thoses devices are allowed (MAC address filter).

The other one is for "untrusted" devices - all other devices where I can't be sure that they are not infected.

Is this level of security efficient to protect my devices from the first network? For exemple, to prevent a virus to spread over the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds pretty solid, a MAC address filter does not add security though and you might want to disable it, as it can be quite inconvenient for home usage.

> So far, this sounds pretty good. But MAC addresses can be easily spoofed in many operating systems, so any device could pretend to have one of those allowed, unique MAC addresses.
>
> MAC addresses are easy to get, too. They’re sent over the air with each packet going to and from the device, as the MAC address is used to ensure each packet gets to the right device.

Which pretty much would defeat it as a safety mechanism.

> **Guest network**
>
> Use for Internet-only devices that don't need local LAN access to other electronics, enable guest isolation.

Another useful thing to do would be to add Google  DNS ( 8.8.8.8 ) and/or OpenDNS ( 208.67.222.222 )
As your ISP's DNS might go down every now and then. In terms of stopping ISP tracking it does little, as they can reverse the IP you're sending requests to.

**Sources:**

[Why you shouldn't use mac address filtering](https://www.howtogeek.com/204458/why-you-shouldn%E2%80%99t-use-mac-address-filtering-on-your-wi-fi-router/)

[decentsecurity.com](https://decentsecurity.com/#/routerwifi-configuration/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and special thanks for external links, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the intention of such separation.

Also note that people on the same wifi network can eavesdrop on each other's traffic with very little effort.

Comment: Ok, good, I will keep this in mind ;) Thanks for your reply